# I did a "flagging-review" which I want to retract

Tags: support, flagging

I've just been asked for a list of answers to confirm or disagree with current flags. I disagreed with the current flags [in one case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492883/principal-component-analysis-in-face-recognition-number-of-eigenvalues/613300#613300) and said so in the answer box. Now I see, that I've misread the question and that flagged answer and my "said-so" is wrong. However when I tried to re-flag, the system dismissed this, saying "you've already flagged". My correction should go to the moderators  that he/she can delete/remove/ignore my comment. How can  do that by flagging (?) or just here-and-now by this question?

Comment: Hmmm... I don't actually have a very good answer to this. Maybe swing by Chat and see if any mod is around and just tell him "nevermind my flag on <q>"? Other ideas welcome.

Comment: Well, @Willie, since I feel also *very* unsure with that flagging I decided now to ignore the list completely if the case is not totally obvious (like spam or litter). My real-life non-habit of flagging/signaling-to-other-ones (don't know the best english word for this:involving authorities for such purposes) is still a rather strong one...